# Strange compiler error: Cannot unify constraint with constraint1

Tags: idris, dependent-type

I am trying to write a library in Idris to work with categories and functors. For my use case, each type can be a category in at most one way (and I would like to use overloading for `id` and `.`), so using an interface suits my needs:

```
infixr 9 .
interface CategoryI (o : Type) where
  data Hom : o -> o -> Type
  (.) : {a : o} -> {b : o} -> {c : o} -> Hom b c -> Hom a b -> Hom a c
  id  : (a : o) -> Hom a a
```

However, for functors, I need a datatype rather than an interface, since there can be multiple functors between the same two categories that I would like to consider.

```
data Functor : Type -> Type -> Type where
  MkFunctor : (CategoryI s, CategoryI t) => 
       (f : s -> t)
    -> (Hom x y -> Hom (f x) (f y))
    -> Functor s t
```

To make use of this, I have written accesser functions:

```
src : Functor s t -> Type
src (MkFunctor fo fm) = s 

tgt : Functor s t -> Type
tgt (MkFunctor fo fm) = t

f_obj : (CategoryI s, CategoryI t) => Functor s t -> (s -> t)
f_obj (MkFunctor fo fm) = fo
```

But I am having problems with the following:

```
f_map : (CategoryI s, CategoryI t) => (f : Functor s t)
     -> (Hom x y -> Hom ((f_obj f) x) ((f_obj f) y))
f_map (MkFunctor fo fm) = fm
```

The compiler complains:

```
 When checking right hand side of f_map with expected type
         Hom x y -> Hom (f_obj (MkFunctor fo fm) x) (f_obj (MkFunctor fo fm) y)

 Type mismatch between
         Hom x y -> Hom (fo x) (fo y) (Type of fm x y)
 and
         Hom x y -> Hom (fo x) (fo y) (Expected type)

 Specifically:
         Type mismatch between
                 constraint1
         and
                 constraint
```

1. I can't even determine what the compiler is complaining abut here. IT somehow can't unify two constraints (which ones?), but the constraints on my constructor and on my `f_map` function are the same, so I don't see what the issue is.
2. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try `:set showimplicits` before loading the file in the repl. That should give a better error message